# Rails: JSON Formatting Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to concatenate two JSON objects and display the result in a JSON.erb file.  Right now, with the following code, I'm getting many extraneous backslashes.  How can I get rid of them?

I expect something like this:

```
{ 
    "success":true, 
    "info":"ok", 
    "data":
        { "steps":
            [
  {
    "id": 243,
    "last": false,
    "name": "Project Overview",
    "position": 0,
    "published_on_formatted": "07/18/2013 14:15:00",
    "images": [
      {...
```

And I'm getting this:

```
{ 
    "success":true, 
    "info":"ok", 
    "data":
        { "steps":
            [
  "{\"id\":721,\"last\":false,\"name\":\"Project Overview\",\"position\":0,\"images\":...
```

My index.html.erb file:

```
{ 
    "success":true, 
    "info":"ok", 
    "data":
        { "steps":
            <% first_step = @project.first_step.to_json(only: [:name, :id, :last, :position], include: {images: {only: [:image_path, :position, :id] } } ).html_safe%>
            <% other_steps = @project.non_overview_steps.to_json(only: [:name, :id, :last, :position], :methods=> :published_on_formatted, include: {images: {only: [:image_path, :position, :id] } } ).html_safe %>
            <% all_steps = first_step + other_steps %>
            <%= JSON.pretty_generate([all_steps]).html_safe %> 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I fixed my json.erb file:

```
{ 
    "success":true, 
    "info":"ok", 
    "data":
        { "steps":
            <% first_step = @project.first_step.as_json(only: [:name, :id, :last, :position], include: {images: {only: [:image_path, :position, :id] } } )%>
            <% other_steps = @project.non_overview_steps.as_json(only: [:name, :id, :last, :position], :methods=> :published_on_formatted, include: {images: {only: [:image_path, :position, :id] } } ) %>
            <% all_steps = other_steps.unshift(first_step) %>
            <%= JSON.pretty_generate(all_steps).html_safe %>
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%=raw ... %>` to avoid escaping.

I would build everything in a multidimensional hash and call `to_json` on it in the end.